# How to change "x" and "y" in a line into "y" and "x" using hash

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying replace strings in a huge file contains many lines.

File.txt

```
line1: "X" = 5.5; "Y" = 7.5;  "Z" = 9.0;
line2: "V" = 66;  "Y" = 3;  "U" = 11.0;
```

so on ...

The Replacement hash (%rhash) contains the map information

```
$rhash{"X"} = "Y"; 
$rhash{"Y"} = "X"; 
$rhash{"Z"} = "A"; 
$rhash{"V"} = "B"; 
$rhash{"U"} = "C";
```

when i tried

```
while (($cur, $cng) = each(%rhash)) {
  $line =~ s/\Q"$cur"\E/\"$cng\"/g;
 }
```

line 1 is change into either

```
"X" = 5.5; "X" = 7.5;  "A" = 9.0;
```

or

```
"Y" = 5.5; "Y" = 7.5;  "A" = 9.0;
```

but the correct change is

```
"Y" = 5.5; "X" = 7.5;  "A" = 9.0;
```

how i can achieve this..

Thanks for your help...

Comment: Note: The hash keys are not  Literals only . The keys can be any pattern that match (\S+)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change them simultaneously. The easiest way is to make a compound executable regexp, and look up the substitution based on what was matched:

```
$re = join("|", map { "\\Q$_\\E" } keys(%rhash));
$str =~ s/$re/$rhash{$&}/ge;
```

Of course, this only works if your replacement keys are literal, and do not have regexp semantics.

**EDIT** If you need things like `$rhash{"\d+"} = "NUMBER"`, this should work:

```
sub find_replacement {
  my ($match, $patterns, $rhash) = @_;
  foreach my $pattern (@$patterns) {
    if ($match =~ s/$pattern/$$rhash{$pattern}/e) {
      return $match;
    }
  }
  die "impossible!";
}

my @patterns = keys(%rhash);
my $re = join("|", @patterns);

$str =~ s/$re/find_replacement($&, \@patterns, \%rhash)/ge;
```